# How to set the thread name twice?

Tags: c#, .net

In my app, I want to name the thread performed by a task using a name relevant to that task, so I can keep the the threads straight. So I use code like

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = this.GetType().Name;
```

where `this` is a class that's dedicated to that task, like `class FilePurgeTask {...}`

The problem is that a thread can be reused with a different class in scope, so the name would then be wrong. And if I try to reset the name, it fails with `System.InvalidOperationException ...This property has already been set and cannot be modified`

Indeed, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.name?view=net-6.0) say "This property is write-once.".

Is there any way to work around it?

Comment: I always assumed this was because the underlying OS function couldn't do it, but apparently [that is not the case](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription). And strange enough, from looking at the .NET 6.0 source, I can't see code that actually throws this exception.

Comment: It is because threads don't actually have a name.  The feature was just recently added to Win10, before that it had to be emulated by intentionally generating an exception that the debugger intercepts.  Just once.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-a-thread-name-in-native-code?view=vs-2022

Comment: @HansPassant But the .NET Thread object seems to have a `Name` property, that doesn't appear to be delegating to an OS thread object to store the name. And they went out of their way to check for null and throw an exception. Why implement it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The documentation is outdated.**

This limitation was removed in .NET 6.0, but apparently the documentation has not been updated. In .NET 5.0, the `Name` property is implemented as:

```cs
        public string? Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (_name != null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_WriteOnce);
                    }

                    _name = value;

                    ThreadNameChanged(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

while in .NET 6.0, this is simply changed to:

```cs
        public string? Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (_name != value)
                    {
                        _name = value;
                        ThreadNameChanged(value);
                        _mayNeedResetForThreadPool = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This simple test works fine when running under .NET 6.0, and the debugger correctly displays changing thread names when single-stepping:

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void NameThread()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Blah";
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Fasel";
        }
```

So, the "workaround" is to upgrade to .NET 6.0 ;-)

Comment: Since it's a simple property, why go to the bother of making it write-once? What did that accomplish?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank I do not know why it was implemented that way, but I suspect it has to do with what Hans Passant is suggesting in a comment above: Early Versions of the .NET Framework had to perform a ugly hack to get this to work, due to missing OS support. And somebody only now found that this restriction was obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a thread-safe [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-6.0) to store the thread ID (key) and the operation it is performing (value).  Using the Thread.Name property won't support the dynamical, reassignable tagging you are looking for.

For what it's worth, the Name property will be null unless it has been set, so you could simply wrap your code in a null check like so to avoid throwing an exception:

```
if(Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = this.GetType().Name;
}
```

Comment: That code isn't thread safe, ironically enough. You know, since you're dealing directly with threads.

Comment: @Blindy - The code is directly from Microsoft's example. :)  However, I would agree that using Thread.Name isn't a good path forward.